# Looping throught data points screw legend of chart

Tags: excel, vba, charts, legend

So, I have a 2D bubble chart with just one series (x=lng, y=lat, z=population).

I want to loop throughout the data points and change the RGB of the bubble to code some extra information about some social groups.

```
Sub PintarColores()
    Dim p As Point

    Worksheets(2).ChartObjects(1).Activate
    For Each p In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points
        p.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = rgbRed
    Next
End Sub
```

this is the test code that put all points as red, after working this out I will add the logic.

So before I run the code, my single serie graph has a legend with one single item (population). After I run it, the color is changed as expected but the legend is changed to a list of the Longitude values (y).

Tried to search arround but can't find why, anyone can shreed some light please?

Thanks!

Comment: This is because you are formatting each data point separately. It is the same as if in the `Format Data Series` pane, click the `Fill & Line`, expand `Fill`, and then select the `Vary colors by point` check box. There is no way to avoid this as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks. Seems thats exactly the case. Too bad. I'll make the legend myself. Thank you m8. I dont know how to validate your answer or give you +1 or whatever.

Comment: If you have only one series, the legend is somewhat redundant, isn't it?

Comment: I presume some of the points will have different colors, otherwise you'd just format the whole series. Could you put the data into separate series according to the color you want?

Answer (score 0):

Axel Richter answered it. Seems there is no way arround this